# Solspace user password reset form - styling?

Tags: solspace-user

The link generated when i complete the forgotten password form sends me to EE member area password reset form.

How do i create my **own** password reset form so i dont have to style EE profile templates?

Comment: I think I ran into this problem myself, and I don't believe it is currently possible.

Comment: I am fairly certain that this used to be possible in previous versions of the plugin, am i correct?

Comment: I think it's because of an EE change. The process used to be that you entered your email in a custom password retrieval form and a new password was sent to you (or maybe it was a password reset link). Now, EE has changed that behaviour so you have to do it through their password reset form. That's what I remember anyway. Show your support for this feature request on the Solspace forums here: http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions/topics/40866